# Porque me marca error al concatenar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos dias tardes o noches, disculpen tengo una duda y es que al querer hacer el select con concat me da el siguiente error
#1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

alguien sabrá que pasa?

```
SELECT CONCAT (usuarios.nombre_persona, ‘ ‘, usuarios.apellido1, ‘ ‘, usuarios.apellido2) AS
nombre_usuario, modulos.nombre_modulo, estatus.nombre_estatus, idiomas.nombre_idioma 
FROM estudiantes_modulos
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = estudiantes_modulos.id_usuario
INNER JOIN modulos ON modulos.id_modulo = estudiantes_modulos.id_modulo
INNER JOIN estatus ON estatus.id_estatus = estudiantes_modulos.id_estatus
INNER JOIN idiomas ON modulos.id_idioma = idiomas.id_idioma;
```

Comment: Prueba a sustituir las comillas simples ‘ ‘ por dobles " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas, creo que es debido a las comillas que has puesto, fijate que no son las que se necesitan, debes poner `' '` no `‘ ‘`, creo que es por eso, porque he usado el `CONCAT()` con tus comillas y ha fallado con el mismo error.

**Solución:**

```
SELECT CONCAT (usuarios.nombre_persona, ' ', usuarios.apellido1, ' ', usuarios.apellido2) AS
nombre_usuario, modulos.nombre_modulo, estatus.nombre_estatus, idiomas.nombre_idioma 
FROM estudiantes_modulos
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = estudiantes_modulos.id_usuario
INNER JOIN modulos ON modulos.id_modulo = estudiantes_modulos.id_modulo
INNER JOIN estatus ON estatus.id_estatus = estudiantes_modulos.id_estatus
INNER JOIN idiomas ON modulos.id_idioma = idiomas.id_idioma;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, no me habia dado cuenta de las comillas :D

Comment: Un placer, si estas en Workbench recuerda que el editor te marca el texto dentro de las comillas de otro color y si tienes comillas y no te lo marca lo más probable es que sea porque no son las correctas.